# Inserir valor "X" após alguns caracteres

Tags: javascript, html

No meu formulário, tem um `textarea` e gostaria de adicionar, a cada 10 caracteres digitados, o carácter `X`, sem submeter a página.

Exemplo:

```
AAAAAAAAAA**X**BBBBBBBBBB**X**EEEEEEEEEE**X**12345678....
```

Conforme o usuário fosse digitando, iria inserindo a cada 10 caracteres. No caso, não preciso de mascará, mas sim adicionar o `X` ao conteúdo.

Alguém já viu ou fez algo do tipo?

---

```js
function mostrarResultado(box, campo_msg_contagem, campo_volumes_hidden) {
  var conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo').value;
  var campo_caracteres = box.length;
  var tamanho_total_codbarras = document.getElementById('tamanho_codbarras').value;
  var resultado = 0;
  if (campo_caracteres > tamanho_total_codbarras) {
    resultado = Math.round(campo_caracteres / tamanho_total_codbarras);
    document.getElementById(campo_msg_contagem).innerHTML = "Lidos = " + resultado + "";
    document.getElementById(campo_volumes_hidden).value = resultado;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(campo_msg_contagem).innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="teste.php" method="post">
  <textarea cols="50" id="conteudo" name="conteudo" rows="30" onkeyup="mostrarResultado(this.value, 'msg_contagem', 'volumes_hidden');"></textarea><br />
  <span id="msg_contagem" style="font-family:Georgia;"></span><br />
  <input type="hidden" id="tamanho_codbarras" name="tamanho_codbarras" value="10" />
  <input type="hidden" id="volumes_hidden" name="volumes_hidden" value="" />
  <input type="submit" /><br>
</form>
```

No caso, peguei essa função de contar caracteres e dei uma alterada básica, que somente soma +1 a cada 10 caracteres digitados, valor definido no `input#tamanho_codbarras`.

O objetivo é quebrar as informações digitadas na próxima tela, com a função do PHP `explode`. No caso, o meu controle de quebra seria pelo caractere `X`, utilizando o exemplo:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
EEEEEEEEEE
12345678
```

Comment: Qual o seu conhecimento de JavaScript? E poderia dizer qual o objetivo de inserir esse caractere no meio do texto?

Comment: Eduardo, compartilhe com a gente o que já tentou. Edite sua pergunta e insira o `HTML` e o `Javascript` que utilizou.

Comment: Se você deseja apenas dividir esse texto no PHP, tenho que dizer que esta solução é péssima. Principalmente por interferir no texto digitado pelo usuário. Imagine você digitando um comentário aqui no site e do nada começa aparecer `X` no meio do seu texto? Extremamente inapropriado. É possível dividir o texto a cada 10 caracteres com PHP sem precisar disso, mas não será possível responder isso nessa pergunta.

Comment: Anderson, vou te resumir a ideia. Possuo um sistema em que carrega uma página somente com um input text para o usuário fazer a leitura do código de barras e o submit é automático. O usuário possui a internet péssima, o que faz o carregamento da página demorar. Me surgiu a ideia de deixar um textarea aberto, como se fosse um notepad ou excel, e o mesmo ler quantos códigos quiser e no final enviar, porém, o código de barras, não possui um carácter para 'controle de quebra', por isso postei a pergunta.

Comment: Certo, mas percebe o incomodo que isso pode gerar, certo? Se realmente deseja que isso seja feito no lado do cliente, utilize o caractere `\n` ao invés do `X`, pois não irá gerar desconforto e ficará visualmente mais agradável. Depois, será preciso analisar como que ocorre a inserção do valor no *textarea* pelo leitor de código de barra. Dependendo de como for, nem todos os códigos das respostas funcionarão, pois dependerá do evento tratado no JavaScript. E mesmo que faça isso no JS, lembre-se também de tratar as informações no PHP. *Nunca confie nos dados do seu usuário*.

Comment: No caso do X, também foi um exemplo. Estou pensando em utilizar ponto e vírgula. Estou com dois leitores em mãos e testando. Um possui enter automático e o outro insere "\n" após a leitura. Já fiz as tratativas no PHP. Realmente, não da para confiar no usuário, mas nesse caso, já fizemos de tudo, mas eles possuem um problema sério com a internet, e como não posso perder o cliente... Mesmo que ele digite qualquer coisa, na próxima tela tem um pente fino que valida a informação. Agradeço pela ajuda e atenção.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var qtd = 10
var qtdX = 0

var div = document.getElementById('t')

div.onkeyup = function(){
  var valor = div.value
  
  if(valor.length == qtd + qtdX){
     qtd = qtd + 10
     qtdX = qtdX + 1
     div.value = valor + 'X'
  }
}
```

```html
 

<textarea id="t"></textarea>
```

Seria mais ou menos isso?

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo um compilado de todas as informações que apresentei:

A primeira, sobre o uso da biblioteca jQuery para uma tarefa tão trivial. É aumentar significativamente o *payload* da aplicação de forma desnecessária, se agravando quando os usuários do sistema possuem problemas de conexão, como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239129/inserir-valor-x-ap%C3%B3s-alguns-caracteres/239139?noredirect=1#comment489729_239129). ([Uma brincadeira sobre esse assunto para descontrair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492))

O segundo cuidado a ser tomado é com o evento tratado no JavaScript. Acredito que a grande maioria dos leitores de código de barra efetuam a cola dos dados no campo e, se assim for, os eventos `keypress`, `keyup` e `keydown` não serão disparados quando for lido um novo código de barra; somente o evento `paste`. Porém, se houver algum leitor que disparem os primeiros eventos, o `paste` não será disparado. Dito isso, o melhor evento JavaScript que pode ser considerado nesse caso é o [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), pois este é disparado sempre que o valor do campo é alterado, independente da fonte.

Assim sendo, considerando o seguinte campo no HTML:

```
<textarea name="conteudo" id="conteudo" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Podemos fazer o início do código JavaScript:

```
const conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");

conteudo.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

Para exemplo, veja funcionando:

```js
const conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");

conteudo.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea name="conteudo" id="conteudo" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Sempre que houver qualquer alteração no conteúdo do campo o novo valor será exibido no console. Agora, basta criarmos a lógica para separar o conteúdo em segmentos de tamanho igual a 10. Para isso, podemos utilizar uma expressão regular bem simples:

```
/.{1,10}/g
```

Isto é, pegue qualquer caractere, diferente da quebra de linha, em uma sequência de 1 a 10 de comprimento, o máximo que for possível. Veja um exemplo bem simples:

```js
console.log("AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEE12345678.".match(/.{1,10}/g))
```

A partir disso, podemos juntar com o código criado anteriormente e definir o novo valor do campo. A lógica será bem simples: sempre que houver uma alteração no campo, pegue o valor atual, separe em segmentos de comprimento igual a 10 (ou menor) e adicione o caractere `\n` entre os mesmos, definindo o novo valor do campo.

Como comentei, será interessante utilizar o caractere `\n`, pois esse não é visível e gera um conforto visual muito melhor, quebrando a linha a cada novo código de barra.

A adição do caractere entre os segmentos poderá ser feito pelo método `join` do *array*:

```js
console.log(['AAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBB', 'EEEEEEEEEE', '123'].join("\n"));
```

Assim, nosso código final ficaria algo como:

```js
const conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");

conteudo.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.match(/.{1,10}/g).join("\n");
});
```

```html
<textarea name="conteudo" id="conteudo" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

> A lógica foi desenvolvida considerando que todos os valores de código de barra possuirão o mesmo comprimento (10, neste exemplo).

Todo esse tratamento é feito no lado do cliente, mas a regra número 1 da web é *nunca confiar nos dados recebidos do usuário*. Um exemplo bem simplório seria de o usuário ter o JavaScript desabilitado no navegador, podendo quebrar completamente a aplicação. Para evitar isso, a validação e tratamento dos dados deverá ser refeita no lado do servidor. A [resposta do Caique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239133/5878) já dá uma breve introdução de como poderia ser feito no PHP.

Comment: Upvote, algumas respostas como esta deveriam ser comparadas a aulas. Em relação ao uso do JQuery, acabo de perceber que ele começou a virar a zona de conforto de muita gente inclusive eu, você meio que me fez abrir os olhos em relação ao uso desnecessário dele e como devemos aos poucos sair da nossa zona de conforto para nos permitir aprender.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').on('blur', function(e){
 var txt = e.target.value.split('');
  var aux = "";
  
  var i=0;
  txt.forEach(function(value, idx){
    if(i==9){
      aux += value + "X";
      i = 0;
    }else{
      aux += value;
      i++;
    }
  });
  alert(aux);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Justificando meu voto negativo, julgo ser completamente desnecessário utilizar jQuery para uma tarefa tão trivial como essa e também não vejo sentido em responder com uma solução à uma pergunta que não faz sentido. Ao meu ver, isso é incentivar péssimas práticas de programação.

Comment: O Jquery está sendo utilizado apenas para agilizar o desenvolvimento.
O restante, estou utilizando es6.
Com relação as boas práticas, existe hoje um péssimo conceito de que as suas praticas são melhores que as minhas e vice versa. O fato é que existem diversas linguagens e diversos frameworks justamente para que se possa resolver o mesmo problema da mesma forma. Boa sorte com todo esse gesso.

Comment: Diego, desculpe-me, mas as más práticas que eu me referia era de fazer a "possível" gambiarra de inserir um caractere `X` no meio de um texto para poder utilizar o `explode` no PHP. Isso seria gambiarra e era isso que eu me referia de péssima prática. Com as novas informações do autor na pergunta isso se mostrou plausível. O que eu criticava era responder qualquer solução sem saber se isso faria sentido ou não. De início não faria, mas agora faz. Só não removi o negativo pois necessita de uma edição na resposta.

Comment: Tudo bem Anderson.  Peço desculpas pela rapidez, mas o fato é que vivemos sob pressão hj em dia e que as vezes nos sentimos ofendidos com coisas do dia a dia. Mas peguei o seu ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa manipular o valor inserido no `<textarea>` após o formulário ser submetido você deve fazer isso através do `PHP`, fazer isso no lado do cliente além de afetar a [experiência do usuário](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-ux-usabilidade-mobile-web/experiencia/#o-que--experincia-do-usurio), não é seguro.

Após o envio do formulário em seu `PHP` utiliza a função [chunk_split](http://www.php.net/chunk_split)
Que permite dividir a string em pedaços.

Supondo que seu `textarea` tenha o propriedade `name='teste'` segue um exemplo em `PHP`:

```
<?php
$teste = $_REQUEST['teste'];

echo chunk_split($teste, 10)
?>
```

Caso você realmente precise executar isso no `client side` segue um exemplo:

A cada 10 `char` Adiciona na `string` o `char` especificado.

```js
function AlteraTexto(str, n) {
    var ret = [];
    var i;
    var len;

    for(i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) { //Percorre a string a cada 10 posições
       ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
    }

    return ret
};
var textarea = document.getElementById('teste');

var resultado = AlteraTexto(textarea.value, 10).join('\n');
textarea.value = resultado;
```

```html
<textarea name="teste" id="teste" rows="6" cols="50">
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEE12345678.
</textarea>
```

Comment: N conhecia a função chuck_split, muito bacana. Problema realmente é, mas é a unica solução que veio em mente com o cenário que possuo. Back-end sempre damos um jeito, agora front-end é o problema rs. No caso, o que preciso, se adaptou com o que o @Wictor Chaves postou. Agradeço pela ajuda e atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Importe o jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Configure como quiser, posição onde vai ficar o X, se vai ser outro caractere e o id do textarea.

```
$(function(){
  var campo = $('#conteudo');
  var posicao = 10;
  var separador = 'X';
  var c = 0;
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
      var target = this;
      return target.split(search).join(replacement);
  };
  campo.keypress(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 32) {
       return false;
    }
    c = (campo.val().replaceAll(separador,'').length);
    if(c % posicao == 0 && c != 0){
      campo.val(campo.val() + separador);
    }  
  });
});
```

Lembrando que, este tipo de código não impede que o usuário envie o textarea de forma incorreta, já que ele pode desativar o javascript ou ate mesmo alterar o código utilizando extensões, firebug ou alguma ferramenta similar.

O correto e verificar o código no servidor, onde o usuário não tem acesso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, cara, utilizo jquery por porque o código fica bem mais simples, e eu não sei qual é o objetivo dele precisar colocar o X, eu respondi com o que ele precisava.

Comment: @Wictor Chaves, o seu fez exatamente o que precisava. O objetivo informei comentários acima. No caso, tentei adaptar o seu código, além de inserir o X, remover os espaços em branco, mas não consegui. Usei um código que tinha aqui. Conseguiria adaptar? Muito obrigado msm.

var $t = document.getElementById('conteudo');
 $t.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  }.bind(this), 0)
 });

Comment: @Eduardo fiz uma alteração, agora não permite ter espaço.

Comment: @Eduardo caso queira remover também as quebras de linhas coloque esta condição aqui no if (code == 32 || code == 13), 32 é o espaço e 13 e o enter.

Comment: ficou perfeito cara, acrescentei o \n tbm, exatamente o q precisava. So um detalhe, vc sabe o prq, digito um caracter e ja insere o "X" no começo? Os demais insere corretamente, apos a quantidade de caracteres definida, so para o inicio do conteudo q começa com X.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, agora não coloca o x no começo